# Pandas create column categories from rows of data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transpose

I have a dataframe like this,

```
id   Name
100  Apple
200  Orange
100  Banana
```

I want to create new columns based on the name, and mark them with 0 or 1.

Like this,

```
id  Name_Apple  Name_Orange  Name_Banana
100  1           0              1
200  0           1              0
```

Id 100 is marked 1 for apple and banana in the name and 0 for orange. Id 200 marked only 1 for orange. I am not actually sure how to do this. Appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df.id, df.Name)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Version 1: If you want to mark the entries with only either 0 or 1:

Use [`pd.get_dummies()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) + [`GroupBy.max()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.max.html), as follows:

```
df_out = (pd.get_dummies(df)
            .groupby('id').max()
            .reset_index()
         )
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_out)

    id  Name_Apple  Name_Banana  Name_Orange
0  100           1            1            0
1  200           0            0            1
```

#### Version 2: If you want to mark the entries as count of occurrences (can be > 1)

If you want the entries to reflect the count of occurrences (can be multiple occurences and thus > 1), you can use [`pd.crosstab()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html), as follows:

```
pd.crosstab(df['id'], df['Name'])
```

**Data Input**

```
    id    Name
0  100   Apple
1  200  Orange
2  100  Banana         <=== multiple occurrences 
3  100  Banana         <=== multiple occurrences
```

**Result**

```
Name  Apple  Banana  Orange
id                         
100       1       2       0
200       0       0       1
```

Note that `Banana` for `id==100`  has a count of 2 instead of either 0 or 1.

You can also use [`pd.get_dummies()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html), as follows:

```
df_out = (pd.get_dummies(df)
            .groupby('id').sum()
            .reset_index()
         )
```

Here, we use [`GroupBy.sum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) instead of [`GroupBy.max()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.max.html)

**Result:**

```
print(df_out)

    id  Name_Apple  Name_Banana  Name_Orange
0  100           1            2            0
1  200           0            0            1
```

Comment: Excellent!! This works perfectly. Very well detailed answer. Thanks.